# Putting a ViewController on top of a TabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Basically I want to make a login screen in my iPhone app before I show my TabBarController. I tried the following approach, adding first to the window subview my TabBarController and on top my LoginViewController. What am I doing wrong or should I do it completely different?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    NSMutableArray *tabItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

    DefaultViewController *dvc = [[DefaultViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *dvc_nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dvc];
    dvc_nc.tabBarItem.title = @"Home";
    //dvc_nc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Default" ofType:@"png"]];
    [tabItems addObject:dvc_nc];
    [dvc release];
    [dvc_nc release];

    OptionsViewController *ovc = [[OptionsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    UINavigationController *ovc_nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ovc];
    ovc_nc.tabBarItem.title = @"Option";
    //ovc_nc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Option" ofType:@"png"]];

    [tabItems addObject:ovc_nc];
    [ovc release];
    [ovc_nc release];

    UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tbc.viewControllers = tabItems;
    self.tabController = tbc;
    [tabItems release];
    [tbc release];

    [self.window addSubview:self.tabController.view];

    LoginViewController *lvc = [[OptionsViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *lvc_nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:lvc];
    [self.window addSubview:lvc_nc.view];
    [lvc release];
    [lvc_nc release];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    NSMutableArray *tabItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

    DefaultViewController *dvc = [[DefaultViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *dvc_nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dvc];
    dvc_nc.tabBarItem.title = @"Home";
    //dvc_nc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Default" ofType:@"png"]];
    [tabItems addObject:dvc_nc];
    [dvc release];
    [dvc_nc release];

    OptionsViewController *ovc = [[OptionsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    UINavigationController *ovc_nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ovc];
    ovc_nc.tabBarItem.title = @"Option";
    //ovc_nc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Option" ofType:@"png"]];

    [tabItems addObject:ovc_nc];
    [ovc release];
    [ovc_nc release];

    UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tbc.viewControllers = tabItems;
    self.tabController = tbc;
    [tabItems release];
    [tbc release];

    [self.window addSubview:self.tabController.view];

    LoginViewController *lvc = [[OptionsViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *lvc_nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:lvc];
[self.tabController presentModalViewController:lvc_nc animated:no];
    [lvc release];
    [lvc_nc release];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday and the `presentModalViewController` as @rckoenes wrote is the correct and working solution

Comment: Aha, seems too work! Is this the proper way to remove the LoginView after i'm done with it?  [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two different views. One will handle the login proccess and one is your "Logged in view" that provides the features of your app. When your app starts up, you add the login view, check username/password and when the login went fine you switch to your second view.

Comment: Do you have a code sample that works with my tabbarcontroller?

Comment: No sorry, am at work and can not provide code samples :/ From the logic: Just create 2 different UIViewControllers one that has your login form in it and get's presented/added in yout applicationDidFinishLaunching method. Put a method in there that validates the entered user credetials and presents your second view (which holds your UITabBar) if the username/password is correct.